# What are "world space" and "eye space" in game development?

Tags: 3d, terminology

I am reading a book about 3D concepts and OpenGL. The book always talks about *world space*, *eye space*, and so on.

- What exactly is a *world* inside the computer monitor screen?
- What is the world space?
- What is eye space? Is it synonymous to projection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588860/what-exactly-are-eye-space-coordinates

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/40741/17516

Comment: SO's duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946652/what-is-world-space-and-eye-space-in-game-development

Comment: See also [The view matrix finally explained](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178643/the-view-matrix-finally-explained/178645#178645).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Before understanding what is the world or eye space, **what is a space?**

In an abstract sense, a geometrical space (e.g. Euclidean Space) is a boundless extent where objects tend to exist. The space defines basic properties that objects living in this space should satisfy. For example in euclidean space **distance** is defined as `Sqrt( vector dot product with itself)`.

**Most people tend to mix between the definition of Space and Coordinate system.** A space as euclidean space defines the properties but doesn't define the coordinate system, **I would say "eye space" is better called "eye coordinates".**

In computer graphic we almost exclusively deal with euclidean space. When you define a Vertex of (X,Y,Z) in euclidean space it doesn't mean anything as is to us.

A more tangible definition would be to define it relative to some coordinate system. For example a  Vertex(X,Y,Z) is relative to eye coordinates. So if Vertex=(0,2,3) relative to the eye coordinates. it means that this vertex is:

> - 0 in the X direction  from  the eye X position.
> - 2 in the Y direction  from  the eye Y position.
> - 3 in the Z direction  from  the eye Z position.
> - And the vertex distance from the eye is sqrt(0^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)=sqrt(13) unit.

**But what is eye coordinates and how do we define a coordinate system ?**

We define a coordinate system by providing [three orthogonal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis)(read: unit length and perpendicular) vectors which resembles orientation, and a position(translation). 
[image]

So if the camera in openGL was defined (note that this is relative to World coordinates):

```
 - Position (0,3,10)
 - Up       (0,1,0)
 - Forward  (0,0,-1)
 - Right    (1,0,0)
```

This means that the viewer is setting at (0,3,10) from the world (0,0,0) and his right is aligned with the world X axis, and his forward is reverse the world Z, and his up is aligned to the World Y.

[image]

**But you talked too much about the eye coordinates, what is the World Coordinates?**

World coordinates is just a fixed parent coordinate system. The eye coordinates itself should be relative to something. This is the global coordinate system that everything is defined relative to.

World Coordinate has a fixed **i**=(1,0,0) in the X direction, **j**=(0,1,0) in the Y direction, **k**=(0,0,1) in the Z direction. These are the vectors that define [Cartesian coordinate system.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)

**But that doesn't make sense! What is the coordinates that World coordinates is defined relative to?**

I would say it's relative to itself, in reality that would be the center of the universe (but that's too simplistic).

But in a more practical sense, I would say in Computer Graphics it's convenient to define world space as the center of the universe (game world) so we can imagine how things can relate to each other.